# Lower bound to a complicated integral over the sphere and a interval

Tags: definite-integrals, estimation, spheres

I'm trying to compute a lower bound to the integral $$\int_{(x,\theta)\in S^{n-1}\times(\frac{\pi}{4},\pi - \frac{\pi}{4}) }\min\{ x_1^2, \ldots, x_n^2, \cot^2\theta \}\cdot\sin^{n+1}\theta\ dx\ d\theta,$$ in terms of $n$ and other constants. This bound should be most tight as possible, an equality would be great but I'm not counting on this.

Until now all my attempts failed, I just can't find or approximate the regions of interest in $S^{n-1}$ (what I tried is to fix $\theta$ and find the corresponding region in $S^{n-1}$ satisfying $x_i^2\leq \cot^2\theta$ for some $i$). If someone can help me, it would be wonderful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok. Let me put all the question here, not just a piece. I'm gonna edit again.

Comment: Now the question makes sense.

Comment: How am I supposed to understand the meaning of all those symbols? What is $x$, what is $\theta$, what is $S$, and what is the space all those variables are living in?

Comment: @HandeBruijn First of all, there is no $S$ in my question. There is $S^{n-1}$, which is a standard notation for the sphere. In any case, let me clarify: $$ S^{n-1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \| x \| = 1 \},  $$
where $\| x\| = \| (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}$ is the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Second, your complaint about the variables, it's written in the integral subscript that $(x,\theta)\in S^{n-1}\times(\frac{\pi}{4},\pi - \frac{\pi}{4})$. It should be clear that $x\in S^{n-1}$ and $\theta \in (\frac{\pi}{4},\pi - \frac{\pi}{4})$, it's an ordered pair.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! As a physicist by education, I'm badly informed about those conventions that seem to be common among mathematicians.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this:
$$\min\{x_1^2, ..., x_n^2, \cot^2\theta\}\cdot\sin^{n+1}\theta \leq \min\{x_1^2, ..., x_n^2\} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n},$$
where I used the approximations $\sin \theta \leq 1, \cot^2\theta \leq 1$ and in the last inequality I took the worst case, which would be $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n$, now that if there is an $x_i > 1/n$, then there is another $x_j < 1/n$ and that would be the minimum. So using $\sqrt{n \cdot x_i^2} = 1$, you get $x_i = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$. Probably there is a better approximation taking more care of the trigonometric functions, but this is all I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I really need something sharper.